# Embedded Jetty handling urls to serve content

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, guice, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded Jetty with Guice and am wondering the best way to handle serving my single page application.

I wish for Jetty to handle requests like so (in priority order):

- `/socket` must be handled by the websocket servlet
- `/fs/read/*`, anything that matches this url I need to be handled by a custom servlet
- `/*`, anything that matches this url should be served from
  the `/web` on the classpath of my Java application assuming it isn't
  handled by the above. If the resource does not exist, then it serves
  `/web/index.html`

Now I am wondering the best way to handle this? It seems heavy handed to use a REST framework as I don't really have any rest services.

Here is currently how I am setting up Jetty:

```
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(DefaultServlet.class);

ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContextHandler.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/");

ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("/web"));
server.setHandler(resHandler);
```

Here is my Guice `ServletModule`:

```
serve("/socket/*").with(WebSocketManagerServlet.class);
serve("/fs/read/*").with(MyCustomServlet.class);
```

However, I am not sure how to do the last rule where it redirects anything not matched to `index.html` and still have jetty send out the right headers which the correct mime types for `css/js/html`, etc. Jetty also probably does some memory mapping and fancy things to serve these quickly which I'd like to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

> *General Note*: `ResourceHandler` is not for [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty) use with an application that has a `ServletContext`.
>   The `ResourceHandler` is ultra-primitive (and very naive) and intended only to support web applications that use raw Jetty handlers only.
>   Do not mix `ResourceHandler` with `ContextHandler`, `ServletContextHandler`, or `WebAppContext`.

Based on what you have asked, I think you want this ...

```java
URL urlToWebDir = findUrlTo("/web");
ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = 
    new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
servletContextHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
servletContextHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(urlToWebDir));
servletContextHandler.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

ErrorPageErrorHandler errorMapper = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
errorMapper.addErrorPage(404,"/"); // map all 404's to root (aka /index.html)
servletContextHandler.setErrorHandler(errorMapper);
```

This is a simpler setup for your `"/web"` path requirement.

The `BaseResource` is the URL (it can be a `jar:file://` or `file://` URL reference) which is used by the `DefaultServlet` to serve your static content.

So that if a request comes in on `/image.png` then `{baseResource}/image.png` is served (and a request on `/icons/avatar.gif` is served from `{baseResource}/icons/avatar.gif`

The `WelcomeFiles` sets up the `index.html` resolving, so that a request on `/` results in serving file `{baseResource}/index.html`.  (also works if request is `/alternate/path/deep/in/your/tree/` then `/alternate/path/deep/in/your/tree/index.html` is served (if it exists).

Bonus note: `DefaultServlet` supports pre-compressed static content serving. Meaning if you gzip your content and keep a copy of it along-side, then the compressed version is served to your users if their browser says it supports compressed responses.   (example: request for `/js/hugelib.js` with old browser that doesn't support compressed responses, then `{baseResource}/js/hugelib.js` is served.  But if browser supports compressed responses, then `{baseResource}/js/hugelib.js.gz` is served instead)

Comment: This covers and works for everything but the case where `/alternate/path/deep/in/your/tree/index.html` does not exist. Here I expect it to serve `{baseResource}/index.html`. I have a solution where I am extending `DefaultServlet` and overriding `doGet`. I've also had to move /web off the classpath. It would be nice if I could find a solution where I didn't have to do this.

Comment: (Update to Answer) That's done with a custom 404 error page mapping.  In the example, any 404 results in a mapping to `/` (which results in `/index.html` being served).   You could just as well map to `/index.html` if you so desire.   But be warned, this isn't a great idea.  Because if you have a 404 on say a CSS, Javascript, or Image then the root HTML will be served (making results over the entire web page very strange)