# jetty 9 add websockets handler to handler list

Tags: jetty, java-websocket

All handlers in that example work apart from the websockets handler

```
       WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
            factory.register(WebsocketsService.class);
        }
    };

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, servletContextHandler, wsHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

it fails with

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

how would be a websockets handler properly configured and added (maybe with a differen Path and Port as the servletContextHandler or could it be added there ?) ?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

1. Don't mix `ResourceHandler` and `ServletContextHandler`, use the built-in static file serving from `ServletContextHandler`, its Resource Base, and the `DefaultServlet` (see [prior answer with details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383973/775715))
2. Don't put anything after your `ServletContextHandler` (if your `ServletContextHandler` is on contextPath `/`).  Once a `ServletContextHandler` is entered (per the contextPath), then it must complete/finish (this is part of the servlet spec), no other handler after that `ServletContextHandler` will ever run. (see [prior answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419106/775715))
3. Don't mix `WebSocketHandler` and `ServletContextHandler`, use the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` in your `ServletContextHandler` and add/manage the websocket endpoints there. (see the [embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook) and the [`WebSocketViaFilter` example](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/websocket/WebSocketServerViaFilter.java) for how to use it)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's actually a lot to check. will come back if successfully.

Comment: it is a bit confusing that the Jetty Documentation actually mentions the Ressource Handler approach in some cases for Embedded solutions as in here [link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html) @Joakim you seem to be the right person to ask, so if you don't mind to comment on that ?

Comment: Again, *don't mix* `ResourceHandler` and `ServletContextHandler`, none of the examples in the documentation do that.   See [the prior answer for more details on why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378028/embedded-jetty-handling-urls-to-serve-content/32383973#32383973).

Comment: Once you start using `ServletContextHandler` (which is superior btw), you no longer use any `Handler` that can serve content (things like `GzipHandler` are ok, as they just manipulate content generated from the `ServletContextHandler`, but don't generate their own content)

Comment: unfortunatetly I get the "Unable to find resource directory" as handled here [link](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DefaultServletFileServer.java) ... the path looks ok...should I post a new question about that ?

Comment: The "Unable to find resource directory" would be more appropriate as either an issue on github, or a new question on stackoverflow.