# HowTo configure the ErrorPageErrorHandler in embedded Jetty?

Tags: jetty, http-status-code-404, embedded-jetty, custom-error-pages

Is it possible to configure the ErrorPageErrorHandler in way that it redirects to a static Page if no content/service is found?

Here is my Code:

```
server = new Server(port);

    Resource webRoot = Resource.newResource(webContent);
    if (!webRoot.exists()) {
        logger.warn("Unable to find root resource:" + webRoot.getName());
    } else {
        logger.info("Root resource is " + webRoot.getName());
    }

    ResourceHandler res = new ResourceHandler();
    res.setBaseResource(webRoot);
    res.setDirAllowed(false);

    //servlet handler
    ServletContextHandler servletCtx = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletCtx.setContextPath("/service");
    servletCtx.addServlet(new ServletHolder("sample", new MyServletSample()), "/sample");

    ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
    errorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "index.html");
    servletCtx.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    // static file handler
    ContextHandler staticCtx = new ContextHandler("/");
    staticCtx.setBaseResource(webRoot);
    staticCtx.setHandler(res);


    // add handlers
    HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
    handlerList.addHandler(servletCtx);
    handlerList.addHandler(staticCtx);

    // add handerList to server
    server.setHandler(handlerList);
```

This code show me index.html on localhost:8080 and I can access the sample service http://localhost:8080/service/sample. However, I want to show a static error page (i.e. documentation) to show up if an error like "404 Not Found" occured.

With this code, the Error handler logs:

> "WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ErrorHandler - No error page found
>   index.html"

. What is correct way/syntax to define the URI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you separating static from your ServletContextHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered before at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383973/775715

Don't mix `ResourceHandler` and `ServletContextHandler` unless you **REALLY** know what you are doing, and fully understand the nature of `javax.servlet.ServletContext` and all of the rules it brings to the table.

See also:

- [What is difference between ServletContextHandler.setResourceBase and ResourceHandler.setResourceBase when using Jetty embedded container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418449/what-is-difference-between-servletcontexthandler-setresourcebase-and-resourcehan/28419106#28419106)
- [Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty)

Here's an example of your setup working with NO ResourceHandler, 1 ServletContextHandler, and a DefaultServlet providing the static file serving.

```java
// servlet handler
ServletContextHandler servletCtx = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletCtx.setContextPath("/");
servletCtx.setBaseResource(webRoot); // what static content to serve
servletCtx.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
servletCtx.addServlet(new ServletHolder("sample", new MyServletSample()), "/service/sample");

ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
errorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "/index.html");
servletCtx.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

// static file serving, and context based error handling
ServletHolder defaultServ = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
defaultServ.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","false");
servletCtx.addServlet(defaultServ,"/");

// add handlers
HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();
handlerList.addHandler(servletCtx);
handlerList.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // non-context error handling
```